# Eclipse Quick fix broken?

Tags: eclipse

I used to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> in Eclipse (4.3) to access refactorings such as "assign statement to local variable".

Unfortunately this refactoring is not offered anymore. When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>, the only proposition I see is "rename in file".

I went in Preferences > Editor to try to find some bad configuration but couldn't find anything.

Did I break something?

edit: 
- The file a is Java file, in a Java project, opened in the Java editor.

Comment: What language is this? What kind of source file in what kind of project?

Comment: Is the file opened in the right editor? If you have opened the file in Eclipse text editor for example, the quick fix will not be available. Right click, choose "open with" and make sure its the correct editor.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, my question wasn't precise enough. I've edited to answer your questions.

Comment: Isn't Ctrl + 2 what you're looking for?

Comment: Ctrl+2 doesn't show any propositions but displays a shortcut list at the lower right of the screen. If I select one of those (like assign to local variable) the code is not refactored.

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternate solution. I'm not sure whether it will solve your problem but you may try using the following configuration:

```
Window --> Preferences --> Java (select your programming language) --> Editor --> Light bulb for quick assists.
```

Mark this option as checked & then click on OK.
After doing this, you should be able to see a light bulb on the current line. Clicking on this bulb should give you the same options as you get by Ctrl + 1.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately clicking the bulb doesn't display and refactoring options.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same experience. Eclipse Version: 2019-12 (4.14.0), it is `build automatically`. I unchecked this in order to speed up eclipse, then I noticed the quick fix only has "rename in this file" left. After I had `build automatically` back, the quick fix works like a fancy.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem.

The solution for me was to reinstall some plugins from the Marketplace. The Darkest Dark Theme from DevStyle was the issue. (don't ask me why)